# Passing a filename through a command-line argument vs. using a string literal in-code

Tags: c++, string, command-line

The following bit of code seems to interpret the slash in the passed filename differently, depending on whether it was passed as a command line argument, or hardcoded by means of a literal. If the image filename `C:\kimba.jpg` is passed in as a command line argument, it works fine:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
    //IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\kimba.jpg", 1);

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

If, on the other hand, I uncomment the second line and comment the first, the same filename causes an exception in that line. I do not know how `cvLoadImage()` is implemented, but it seems (according to the debugger) that in both cases the same content is being passed to the function. So why does the hardcoded filename cause an exception and not the command-line argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash with a backslash:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\\kimba.jpg", 1);
```

Comment: I understand, but why does it not work like that with the command line argument?

Comment: When passed as a command line parameter, the single backslash is interpreted exactly as a backslash.  The backslash in a C/C++ string literal is a special character that is used to specify certain characters (e.g., \t for a tab).

Comment: At least, on Windows it's exact. On other OSes, you may have to escape the backslash through the shell. It's important to distinguish between *what you type*, and *what string value results*. The string value resulting from `"C:\kimba.jpg"` in C, is the same as the one from `"C:kimba.jpg"`, and contains no backslash characters. The string value from `"C:\\kimba.jpg"` in C is the same as the one from `C:\kimba.jpg` at the Windows command prompt. Backslashes in runtime string values aren't interpreted specially, neither are ones at the command prompt, but ones in string literals in source are.

Comment: @Steve:  Good point.  The "c:\" locked my mind into windows mode.

Answer (score 3):

the '\' character is the escape character in C++.  To get a '\' character literal, you need to escape it (note the double '\'):

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\\kimba.jpg", 1);
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"C:\\kimba.jpg"` - `\` is used to escape special characters such as `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Backslash in string literals is an escape character, while in command line argument it is interpreted as-is. So in the second case the file is not found and you get an exception.